# Cannot place view to the middle of the CardView ConstraintLayout as there's theView below with Gone visibility

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have the following CardView:

```
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/bank_account_cv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margin_16"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/margin_8">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/margin_8">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/bank_account_rb"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_22"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_22"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_16"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/bank_account_tv"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/bank_account_tv" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/bank_account_tv"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/margin_16"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_14"
                    android:text="@string/title_on_bank"
                    android:textAlignment="textStart"
                    android:textColor="@color/new_text_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/default_text_size_14"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/bank_account_rb"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/bank_account_expanded_cl"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bank_account_tv">

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/bank_account_divider"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_16"
                        android:alpha="0.5"
                        android:background="#000001"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:id="@+id/iban_hint_tv"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_16"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:text="@string/step7_iban_hint"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bank_account_divider" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                        android:id="@+id/step1_phone"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/height_edittext"
                        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margin_16"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_2"
                        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext_with_border"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/iban_hint_tv" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

As you can see, there's the part which is always visible (RadioButton and TextView) and the part, which has visibility gone by default, but becomes visible in some situation. Now this CardView looks like this:

[image]

And here's the way how it looks when Gone part is visible:

[image]

On the first picture textview isn't placed in the middle of the screen, and Card looks a bit cut in the bottom. I tried to tie textview to the bottom of the screen also, but in this situation it has wrong behavior when Gone part is visible. So, what's the best solution to place it in the middle of card when view has Gone part and keep the same top margin when Gone part is Visible. I will appreciate any help, thanks in advance!

Comment: I think in both the cases the top content is not in center in the second image it's just giving an illussion due to that divider line

Comment: @PraveenSP, I agree with you. But how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First thing is try to reduce constraint layout hierarchy. You can do this using only one constraint layout.
>
> Second, for multiple views visibility, you can use Group widget of constraintlayout. For more detail: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/Group

[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bank_account_cv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_15sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:background="@color/color_blue_pin"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/margin_8">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/margin_8">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
            android:id="@+id/bank_account_rb"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_22"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_22"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_16"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/bank_account_tv"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/bank_account_tv" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/bank_account_tv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_14"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:text="title_on_bank"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="@color/color_black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_15ssp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/bank_account_rb"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/bank_account_divider"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:alpha="0.5"
            android:background="#000001"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bank_account_tv" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/iban_hint_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_16"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="step7_iban_hint"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bank_account_divider" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/step1_phone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margin_16"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_2"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_custom_edittext"
            android:maxLines="1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/iban_hint_tv" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
            android:id="@+id/group"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="step1_phone,iban_hint_tv,bank_account_divider" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Constrain the bottom of the `bank_account_expanded_cl` layout to the bottom of the parent:

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

Then constrain the bottom of the `bank_account_tv` TextView to the top of the `bank_account_expanded_cl` layout:

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bank_account_expanded_cl"
```

This way when the layout is hidden the constraints are still enforced, effectively making the TextView constrained to the bottom and centering it in the CardView.

You might also need to add a bottom margin to the `step1_phone` EditText since you have a 15dp margin on the top of `iban_hint_tv` to make it look even when the layout is expanded. Or just add a vertical margin/padding to `bank_account_expanded_cl` itself instead.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you... I have added a new divider view and set the constraints to it...

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
      android:id="@+id/bank_account_cv"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margin_16"
      android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
      android:background="@android:color/white"
      app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/margin_8">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/margin_8">

      <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
          android:id="@+id/bank_account_rb"
          android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_22"
          android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_22"
          android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_16"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/bank_account_tv"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/bank_account_tv" />

      <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
          android:id="@+id/bank_account_tv"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/margin_16"
          android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_14"
          android:text="@string/title_on_bank"
          android:textAlignment="textStart"
          android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
          android:textSize="@dimen/default_text_size_14"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/bank_account_rb"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

      <View
          android:id="@+id/content_divider"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="1dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
          android:alpha="0.5"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bank_account_tv" />

      <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
          android:id="@+id/bank_account_expanded_cl"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:visibility="visible"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/content_divider">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/bank_account_divider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:alpha="0.5"
            android:background="#000001"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/iban_hint_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_16"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="Some other Text"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bank_account_divider" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/step1_phone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margin_16"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_2"
            android:maxLines="1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/iban_hint_tv" />

      </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

  </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```